# Powershell: Migrating from AzureAD to Az module - but cannot find a replacement for Get-AzureADUserMembership

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm having a strange issue - as I'm having trouble with locating the **Az** module pendent to the **AzureAD** cmdlet *Get-AzureADUserMembership*.

How do I retrieve a list off groups for a particular user, when *Get-AzADUserMembership* does not seem to exist?

Regards, Stickybit

Answer (score 0):

***I couldn't find equivalent for Get-AzureADUserMembership in Azmodule but when i tried with the below commands:***

```
$groups=Get-AzADGroup 
#$members=Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupDisplayName $name  
$memberobj="<give the user object id here for which you need to find groups>"  

foreach($group in $groups)  
{  
$members= Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true

foreach($member in $members)  
{  

if($member.ObjectId -eq $memberobj)  
{  
Write-output $group.DisplayName
}  
}
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

It is in under preview process you cannot use in production side.
Reach out to the [microsoft support team](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) for detailed information.

In few cases, the behavioral difference of the Microsoft Graph API from the AzureAD Graph API will induce a breaking change.

***Reference:***
[Azure AD to Microsoft Graph migration for Azure command line tools. - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-tools-blog/azure-ad-to-microsoft-graph-migration-for-azure-command-line/ba-p/2836666)